# Why does a simple multiplication DOES NOT work in ampscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

```js
<script runat="server" language="ampscript">
    SET @x = 100
    SET @y = 5

    SET @output1 = @x * @y  // Why this does NOT work!

    SET @output2 = Multiply(@x,@y)   //And only this works!!


</script>
    Output = %%=v(@output1)=%% <br/>        //Output = 100 
    Output = %%=v(@output2)=%%              //Output = 500
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/syntaxGuide.htm) (and more clearly stated in the [AMPscript Guide](https://ampscript.guide/math-functions/)), all math can only be done via the functions listed in the syntax guide [MULTIPLY(), SUBTRACT(), ADD(), etc.] unlike other languages that can use the operators of [-,+,*,/].

> In contrast to many other scripting languages that use operators like +, -,*, and \, AMPscript uses a set of functions for addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. AMPscript also includes specific math functions for performing modulo operations and generating random numbers.
>
> - AMPscript Guide

In AMPscript these operators are ignored and in fact can potentially cause errors or incorrect output.